# openpop.net cannot delete message although using disconnect()

Tags: c#

I am using client.deletemessage, then
client.disconnect
and anyway the code comes to dispose which should use the disconnect (and QUIT).
Nevertheless some messages will not be deleted - they stick in the system:

When I directly launch the console application - it deletes everything.
When I use a scheduler it deletes some/all of the messages but not always all.
I tried another scheduler and same thing - a matter of luck.

Furthermore - in both cases the message is marked as delete (I see it as read on outlook after the run ).

So via scheduler (although using the same user account as my own) it looks like the disconnect is not reliable ???

Comment: Please add an example.

Answer (score 0):

added 
client.DeleteAllMessages();
client.Disconnect(); (although the latter was supposed to kick in anyway)seems to help.